# How to override an admin theme template?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, php, template, overrides

I would like to override `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml`

i'm currently using an extension that overrides `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml`
with a file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/extname/page/header.phtml`

i have recently made changes to the page.phtml file, but i would like to override it in the right way, but i'm not sure how. i was going through the codes to see how the extension developers override header.phtml but i cant figure it out.

can anyone tell me how to override this specific file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your extension's admin layout file or create one if you don't have yet.

`default/default/layout/your_xml.xml`

and add this in default section:

```
<layout>
    <default>
       <reference name="root">
          <action method="setTemplate">
              <template>your_path/page.phtml</template>
          </action>
       </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I haven't tested but should work. Good luck.

Comment: Why do we need an extension to override adminhtml, but we don't need one for frontend theme?

Answer (score 38):

You can declare a new primary theme for your admin area by customizing config (e.g. app/etc/local.xml) with the following:

```
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <default>your_theme</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

This will just set another level of fallback, and you can copy this and other custom templates/layout/etc under the right path in app/design/adminhtml/default/your_theme/

Comment: Thank you for this, this should be the accepted answer in my opinion as it allows for much easier modification of ALL adminhtml template files without having to explicitly configure a new view script for each file.

Comment: It should be "<template>your_theme</template>".

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'm not believe this is the correct way of overriding `adminhtml` templates. But I try this approach and it works, So just wanna share.

Add this to your custom Module `config.xml`

```
<stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <default>default</default>
                    <template>mycustom</template>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
</stores>
```

Now You can just override by copying templates from `default` to `mycustom`
`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\history.phtml` `app\design\adminhtml\default\mycustom\template\sales\order\view\history.phtml`