# How can I extend adminhtml JavaScript methods with custom logic?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, adminhtml, magento-1.14, theme-fallback

I have extended several JavaScript methods of the `Product.Config` class on the frontend website to apply some custom business logic, but I need to share the same customizations with the sales order create page in adminhtml.

On the frontend I created a customized version of the  `catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` template in my theme, which injects some custom data for configurable products.

I also needed to extend the `Product.Config` class to make use of the data. I used [the wrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22962918/1737136), which allows me to call the parent method and avoid duplicating the whole method (or worse, the entire file) but also inject some new logic as well.

```
Product.Config.prototype.getOptionLabel = Product.Config.prototype.getOptionLabel.wrap(function(parentMethod, option, price){
    var str = parentMethod(option, price);

    // Custom logic

    return str;
});
```

I then added it to the `catalog/product/view` page like this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>custom/configurable.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
<catalog_product_view>
```

Obviously, I don’t want to have this logic duplicated in two places, so how do I leverage my existing logic on the adminhtml side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to customize the adminhtml equivalent of the template mentioned above, which would be: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/configurable.phtml`.

The best way to accomplish this is to add a [custom theme to your adminhtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79136/20131) so that you can override the template by copying it to `app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/configurable.phtml` and making your edits there.

Second, since you are talking about Magento 1.9, make sure to define your `app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/etc/theme.xml` to define your theme fallback order, as well as define a layout update file where you can add the shared JavaScript file to the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>default/default</parent>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <custom_adminhtml_sales>
                <file>custom/sales.xml</file>
            </custom_adminhtml_sales>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

Now your layout updates can be added to the [correct adminhtml page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12799959/1737136) in the `app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/layout/custom/sales.xml` file. This will allow the same JavaScript logic from the frontend to be applied on the adminhtml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>custom/configurable.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```