# Adding the Order Statuses to the Magento Permission Rules

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status, permissions, order-state

How to add the order statuses to the permission rules in order to be able to assign a particular order status of a state to a user where he/she is able to change the status for an order only if the permission of that particular order status is granted to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not support the desired behaviour natively.

You can achieve it using the following solution though it isn't the most tidy of approaches.

You'll need to [override an admin theme template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79132/how-to-override-an-admin-theme-template), or edit the base template file though this is not recommended as it will prevent your ability to upgrade in future.

`app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml`, replace lines 34 through 36 from:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStatuses() as $_code=>$_label): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $_code ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getOrder()->getStatus()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_label ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php
  $admin_user_role = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole()->getData();
  $restricted_statuses = array('Restricted Status 1', 'Restricted Status 2'); //etc
?>
<?php foreach ($this->getStatuses() as $_code=>$_label): ?>
    <?php if(in_array($_label, $restricted_statuses)): ?>
    <?php //restricted role ?>
        <?php if ($admin_user_role['role_name'] == 'Your Restricted Role'): ?>
        <?php //in which case the user has permission to access this role ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_code ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getOrder()->getStatus()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_label ?></option>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php //unrestricted status ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_code ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getOrder()->getStatus()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_label ?></option>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This way, you're able to specify the restricted statuses using the `$restricted_statuses` array, and only provide access to the `"Your Restricted Role"` user.

This obviously isn't ideal as it's hard coded, but using a bit of intuition you'd be able to set up a table in the database to handle this.

Comment: thank you, is there any way that I override the base template in such a way that I don't lose the changes I mad or don't get any problem while the Magento is upgraded to a new version.